# Notification in Service on isolated process throws NPE

Tags: android, service, process, android-notifications

I get a NullPointer, every time I try to send a Notification from a 
service that runs on a isolted service.

The exception:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:136)
        at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:109)
        at de.nwo.client.modules.service.NwoService.createOrUpdateNotification(NwoService.java:66)
        at de.nwo.client.modules.service.NwoService.access$000(NwoService.java:23)
        at de.nwo.client.modules.service.NwoService$1.run(NwoService.java:47)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest declaration:

```
        <service
        android:name=".modules.service.NwoService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:isolatedProcess="true"
        android:process=":nwoService"/>
```

The service implementation:

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(SERVICE_TAG,"started!");
    startLogging();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

private void startLogging() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createOrUpdateNotification();
            startLogging();
        }
    },3000);
}

private void createOrUpdateNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setColor(Color.GREEN)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentText(String.valueOf(++increment))
            .setContentTitle("NWO");
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification f = builder.build();
    Log.d(SERVICE_TAG, "nm: " + mNotificationManager + " , notification: " + f);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, f); //npe here
}
```

If I remove the lines android:isolatedProcess="true" and android:process=":nwoService" from the manfiset, everything works
like intended. Does anybody know the reason? Why can't I use the 
NotificationManager from an isolated process?

Comment: what's printed on the log?

Comment: THis is a bit of a guess, but-  the point of an isolated process is to not allow communication with other processes.  Notifications work via sending messages to another process (a system process) that actually handles the UI of notifications.  I would expect that since you can't do any cross-process communication from an isolatesProcess, you can't do notifications from one either.

Comment: @budius I've already added the log.  You can find it direct at the top of my post.  :)

Comment: @GabeSechan I think you are right on that. I found this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/pk45eUFmKcM Basically Hackborn says that the isolatedProcess flag is for adding an additional security layer for running code, where you can't guarantee that the code doesn't have any security holes. So they won't let us comminucate to "the outer world" here.